# Computer has right arrow key constantly 'held down'

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

When I use the computer, whenever a situation occurs where the <strike>left</strike> **right** arrow key would have an action, the computer seems to have this key held down.

To explain (that wasn't very clear), if I'm on Facebook photo viewer, the arrow keys can be used to move to the next or previous photo. However, it feels as if the right arrow key is constantly down, as the viewer scrolls through all the photos. Another example is that in any text field, the cursor runs through the text to the end.

This basically makes any text input impossible as I cannot go back to correct things <strike>(hence the reason for any mistakes in this post)</strike>.

This doesn't happen in perhaps the first few minutes of the computer turning on, which suggests to me that it is software-related rather than hardware. Also, I have tried switching to another keyboard and the problem still occurs.

I am running Windows XP SP3 on a Dell Latitude S630.

Comment: Left or right? You talk about moving to "end of line" but that's moving right, not left.

Comment: Sorry, your right (it should be right) - I would edit it if I could but due to the nature of the problem I can't!

Comment: Try rollbacking your keyboard driver from device manager.

Comment: @Josh How can I do that?

Comment: I can't remember how to do it in XP, but hopefully it's almost the same as in Win7.  Control Panel > Device Manager > Expand Keyboard category > Right Click your keyboard (there is probably only one) > Select Properties >  Go to Driver Tab > Select Rollback driver.  You can also try updating your driver from the same screen.

Comment: @Josh "No previous backup found" :(

Comment: Did you try to update the driver?  It should be an option on the same page.

Comment: Another thing you can try is connecting a second keyboard, make sure it is functioning properly, then restart the computer.  After the restart, do not touch the bad keyboard at all and see if the problem still arises.

Comment: If you believe it is software related, perhaps try booting into safe mode, or disabling some of your startup items to attempt to isolate the problem.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone suggested trying with an external USB keyboard yet?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem once the other way around, my cursor was constantly moving to the left. I found out eventually it was caused by the Logitech software that came with my mouse.

I'd suggest uninstalling any keyboard or mouse software and reverting back to default windows drivers for those. If the problem goes away, check for newer drivers.

Answer (score 2):

On most keyboards, pressing that exact same key for a while and then releasing will fix the issue.
If you have 3rd party KB or mouse software, try uninstalling it to see if it makes a difference.
Alternately, test the KB at a BIOS screen. That way all the software part is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take off the laptop's original keyboard and test this issue with an external USB one. If you are not familiar with taking laptops apart, don't worry - removing keyboard is pretty easy, just google it for your specific model if you are not sure.

Blame the software if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also bring up Windows Virtual Keyboard to see if the right arrow key is held there; Go to Start > All Programs > Accessories > Accessibility > On-screen Keyboard and click the right arrow key if it is greyed out/highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I have a remote controller for movies, turned out a button in it was pressed while it was in the drawer under a table while the USB dongle was attached to my PC...

Answer (score 0):

> the cursor jumps to the end of the text.

This sounds more like you have <kbd>End</kbd> being pressed rather than <kbd>→</kbd>.
 (See comments)

---

Try pressing and releasing <kbd>→</kbd>; perhaps it's stuck down? It could also be some software is firing "down" events but not matching "up" events, so this would be a temporary fix.

You mention running on a laptop. Is it possible that your wrist is engaging the touchpad whilst typing? Try disabling the touchpad.

---

> I have tried switching to another keyboard and the problem still occurs.

Is this using an external usb keyboard, or replacing the laptop's keyboard? If the laptop keyboard is generating the rogue key presses then adding another keyboard wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's end, that key is way up in the corner and the cursor specifically goes through each character rather than jumping down line by line

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to 'sticky keys'.

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> five or more times, then open the underlined thing, and **uncheck all**.

Click **Apply** then **Ok**.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The arrow keys are **not** sticky keys.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.keyboardtester.com

Check which key is enabled. It may be the home key or end key enabled.

I had the same problem. 
Check with this software and solve the issue. Its not a software issue. Its a physical issue.
Whether you can check if your keyboard is time for replacement or not.

Answer (score -2):

Just uninstall all keyboards and mice drivers from device manager. Restart PC, existing keyboard and mouse drivers will be automatically installed.
Boom! Problem is solved.

Comment: This is basically the same as  [R-D’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/613274/354511#613341)  from seven years ago.